# To apply a script to specific tables only

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

The following script helps to make html tables to have rows of alternating colors:

```
<script type = "text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("tr:even").css("background-color", "#e8eef4");
});
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("tr:odd").css("background-color", "#fff");
});
</script>
```

It works ok, but the problem is that it applies this rule to all tables in its scope, and I'd like it to be applied to several tables only.

How I could apply such a script to specific tables only?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change your selector (`tr:even` or `tr:odd`) to `.CLASSNAME tr:even` and `.CLASSNAME tr:odd` - then add `CLASSNAME` to your containing tables where you want the stripes.

Answer (score 2):

You should forget about using javascript and just use CSS

```
<style>
    .myTable tr:nth-child(even) { background-color: #c5c5c5;  }
    .myTable tr:nth-child(odd) { background-color: #fff;}
</style>

<table class="myTable">
    <tr>
        <td>asdf</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>asdf</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>asdf</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>asdf</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Here's a fiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/ZxvpX/1/

This will increase performance and reduce overhead simply because it doesn't require any additional libraries for such a menial task.

## EDIT

as pointed out this doesn't work in IE. So you will need to load up the jQuery plugin to fix IE's broken system.

```
<RANT>  
    COME ON ALREADY MICROSOFT!!! WE ALL KNOW YOUR DEVELOPERS 
    READ THESE QUESTIONS ON STACKOVERFLOW AND FULLY UNDERSTAND
    THE FRUSTRATION BEING EXPRESSED ON A DAILY BASIS. 
    GET WITH THE PROGRAM ALREADY!
</RANT>
```

Comment: except the IE support but still, one up =)

Answer (score 1):

You can narrow the selector and combine your code, like this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $(".selector tr:even").css("background-color", "#e8eef4");
  $(".selector tr:odd").css("background-color", "#fff");
});
```

`.selector` is an example, but whatever your can identify those tables on will work, or if this is part of an AJAX request, use `$("tr:even", context)` instead.

Answer (score 1):

Set table classes for the tables you want it applied to such as

```
<table class="even-odd"/>
   <tr></tr>
   <tr></tr>
</table>
```

Then Adjust your jQuery selectors to select all tables with the appropriate class and the descendant tr of that table only.

```
<script type = "text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("table.even-odd tr:even").css("background-color", "#e8eef4");
});
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("table.even-odd tr:even").css("background-color", "#fff");
});
</script>
```

I would personally just suggest using CSS properties

```
table.even-odd tr:nth-child(even) { background-color: #e8eef4;  }
table.even-odd tr:nth-child(odd) { background-color: #fff;}
```